# how to fix 'name' is undefined on object error?

Tags: go

I'm making an API post request to bigpanda using Go.

https://docs.bigpanda.io/reference#create-plan

I have below code and when I try to make API post getting `name` is `undefined` on object error.

```
2019/08/23 18:38:04 {
  "status" : "failure",
  "error" : "{\"obj\":[{\"msg\":[\"'name' is undefined on object: {\\\"maintenance_plan\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"scheduled host maintenance\\\\\\\",\\\",\\\"condition\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"condition\\\\\\\": {\\\\\\\"=\\\\\\\": [\\\\\\\"host\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"prod-api-1\\\\\\\"]},\\\",\\\"start\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"start\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"1566514810\\\\\\\",\\\",\\\"end\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"end\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"156651600\\\\\\\"\\\"}}\"],\"args\":[]}]}"
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)


type Maintenace_Plan struct {
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    //Condition  map[string]map[string][]string  `json:condition`
    Condition   string `json:"condition"`
    Start      string `json:"start"`
    End        string `json:"end"`
}


type Payload struct {
    Maintenace_Plan Maintenace_Plan `json:"maintenance_plan"`
}

func main() {
    name        := `"name": "scheduled host maintenance",`
    create_plan :=  `"condition": {"=": ["host", "prod-api-1"]},`
    start_time  := `"start": "1566514810",`
    end_time    := `"end": "156651600"`

    data := Payload{
        Maintenace_Plan: Maintenace_Plan{
            Name:       name,
            Condition:  create_plan,
            Start:      start_time,
            End:        end_time,
        },
    }

    payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    body := bytes.NewReader(payloadBytes)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.bigpanda.io/resources/v2.0/maintenance-plans", body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer <token>")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body_1, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(string(body_1))

}
```

Looks like body is incorrect.
Is there any way to fix the code.

Comment: As you say, the problem is the body--which this code didn't generate. So this code can't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

That error message is probably being returned from the API Call you're making and not the JSON Marshal. I suspect it's due to the way you're marshalling your payload - you're writing JSON to the fields and then JSON marshalling it so you end up with a payload that looks like:

```
{"maintenance_plan":{"name":"\"name\": \"scheduled host maintenance\",","condition":"\"condition\": {\"=\": [\"host\", \"prod-api-1\"]},","start":"\"start\": \"1566514810\",","end":"\"end\": \"156651600\""}}
```

Notice the double "name: "\name\".

The way to fix it would be to do something like:

```
data := Payload{
   MaintenancePlan: MaintenancePlan{
      Name: "scheduled host maintenance",
      Condition: map[string][]string{
         "=": []string{"host", "prod-api-1"},
      },
      StartTime: "1566514810",
      EndTime: "156651600",
   },
}

var buf bytes.Buffer
err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(data)
if err != nil {
  // Handle me
}
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "https://foo/bar", &buf)
// continue
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/J6wrsLYkvwF